# Scrape table with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I have a table structure that looks like this :

```
<tr><td>
<td>
<td bgcolor="#E6E6E6" valign="top" align="left">testtestestes</td>
</tr>
<tr nowrap="nowrap" valign="top" align="left">
<td nowrap="nowrap">8-K</td>
<td class="small">Current report, items 1.01, 3.02, and 9.01
<br>Accession Number: 0001283140-16-000129 &nbsp;Act: 34 &nbsp;Size:&nbsp;520 KB
</td>
<td nowrap="nowrap">2016-09-19<br>17:30:01</td>
 <td nowrap="nowrap">2016-09-19</td><td align="left" nowrap="nowrap"><a href="/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&amp;filenum=001-03473&amp;owner=include&amp;count=100">001-03473</a>
<br/>161891888</td></tr>
```

That is one row of data. This is my script using beautifulSoup. I can get the `<tr>` and `<td>` just fine. But they are in a separate list.

```
for tr in (soup.find_all('tr')):
        tds = tr.find_all('td')
        print tds
```

My problem is how can I get the data from two separate `<tr>` and make it look like they're one row of data. I am trying to get the text between `<td>`

Comment: What are you trying to get?

Comment: So you want to pair every two trs?

Comment: yes correct @PadraicCunningham

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pair them up, create an iterator from `soup.find_all('tr')` and *zip* them into pairs:

```
it = iter(soup.find_all('tr'))
for tr1, tr2  in zip(it, it):
        tds = tr1.find_all('td') + tr2.find_all("td")
        print(tds)
```

The equivalent with slicing would be to start with a different start pos and use a step of 2:

```
it = soup.find_all('tr')
for tr1, tr2  in zip(it[::2], it[1::2]):
        tds = tr1.find_all('td') + tr2.find_all("td")
        print(tds)
```

Using *iter*  means you don't need to shallow copy the list.

Not sure how having an uneven amount of trs fits into the logic as there would be nothing to pair but if there is you can use [*izip_longest*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest):

```
from itertools import izip_longest # python3 zip_longest

it = iter(soup.find_all('tr'))
for tr1, tr2  in izip_longest(it, it):
        tds = tr1.find_all('td') + tr2.find_all("td") if tr2 else []
        print(tds)
```

Comment: this assumes that the count of `<tr>` is always even?

Comment: @wasp, if they weren't your question does not make sense, how can you pair up a single row? Regardless you can use `izip_longest/zip_longest`, I will edit

Comment: woops. sorry, you're right. I tried it and it works! Thank you. I used the first solution

Comment: No worries, izip_longest/zip_longest would catch the case where you had an uneven amount.